# SQL/ACCESS UPDATE

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

I am trying to update a table in Access using SQL in a VBScript. I have 2 statements that reference 2 tables.  The first statement works and the second doesn't.  The only difference in the two is a field name, and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I've been working on it for 6 hours now. Could anyone assist?

This works

```
DB.Execute "UPDATE tblDEBIT20 SET CONTROL = '" & strControl & "' WHERE DEBIT_NUM = '" & strDebit & "'"
```

This doesn't

```
DB.Execute "UPDATE tblDEBIT20 SET CURRENTNAME = '" & strCurrent & "' WHERE DEBIT_NUM = '" & strDebit & "'"
```

The error I get is

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: What are the values of strControl and strCurrent?

Comment: Search here  for *[ms-access] No value given for one or more required parameters* to find dozens of prior questions that have been answered already. And any question about why your SQL doesn't work needs to contain the schema (column definitions) for the database, including column data types. Most likely, you're quoting something that doesn't require quoting, or not quoting something that should be; it's impossible to tell, however, because you've failed to provide the information in your question.

Comment: I can't give exact values, but the strControl is a 22 character value of 20 numbers and 2 letters and the current name is someone's name.  Both are set as text fields with 255 characters.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  I thought perhaps I was typing something incorrectly in the second one and was looking more for a fresh pair of eyes.  I'm still new to SQL, and like I said earlier, I've been staring at it for 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point being made by both Ken and Robert is that you most likely have a name with an apostrophe in it. You can either replace all single quotes (') with something else or try another quote delimiter.

See if this works for you ***(escaping double quotes when used inside double quotes)***.

```
DB.Execute "UPDATE tblDEBIT20 SET CURRENTNAME = """ & strCurrent & """ WHERE DEBIT_NUM = """ & strDebit & """"
```

A tip for you in future debugging - add a `Debug.Print strCurrent` before the execute command - then when it fails you can easily see what the issue is - or at least tell us what value it failed on.